# Проблема с исключениями в доступе

Tags: cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне требуется обеспечить взаимодействие в сети таким образом, чтобы администратор мог отправлять запросы на офисные ПК, но офисные ПК не могут отправлять запросы администратору.
Также имеются камеры, которые могут посылать и получать запросы от администратора, но не могут получать и отправлять запросы от офисных ПК.
В настройках маршрутизатора я использовал расширенные списке доступа и соотнес их с соответствующими интерфейсами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После проделанных манипуляций офисные ПК действительно не могут отправлять запросы в другие подсети, но так же и не могут получать запросы от устройств администратора. Похоже, что я неправильно понял, как надо задавать исключения в списках доступа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]